# Executable `python` not found while using Github Desktop

Tags: python, git, github, github-desktop

Been stuck on this error for a while. I can't seem to figure it out. Any ideas out there? This occurs when I try to commit changes to a feature branch.

I can however, commit from the command line.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have either python, pyhon2, or python3 installed?

Comment: Note that most installers name the Python 3 binary `python3` (to distinguish it from the Python 2 binary). You didn't mention the operating system you're on, but if you're on anything not-Windows then you could alias `python` to `python3`, or put a symlink on your path to the `python3` executable.

Comment: Yes I do have python installed and I'm on MAC.

Comment: matthewnguyen@Matthews-MacBook-Pro ~ % which python3

/opt/homebrew/bin/python3

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a virtual environment (`.venv`) for your project? If so, pylint might only be installed in the scope of that environment, which GitHub desktop will not have access to.

Comment: Yes but GIthub Desktop has been working up until recently. WIll have to investigate the yaml file above as I wasn't familiar with that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have pre-commit installed to run your different checks before a commit can proceed. If the GitHub Desktop environment doesn't know that the `python` command should go to `python3`, or if that environment doesn't recognize your symlinks or aliases, then this could happen.

You should be able to define a default version of the language in your .pre-commit-config.yml (snippet copied from https://pre-commit.com/#overriding-language-version):

```
default_language_version:
    # force all unspecified python hooks to run python3
    python: python3
```

That shouldn't affect your CLI-based commits, but the additional clarity should help GitHub Desktop complete those checks appropriately.